# SQLlite query for getting data BETWEEN 2 dates not working

Tags: android, database, sqlite, datetime

I am using date sqlite in android and want to filter the date between two dates. I don't what the hell is wrong with my query? Its not giving error , but also not giving result. 
**I think I am doing something wrong with BETWEEN date AND date function**

```
SELECT * FROM trip_mark WHERE file_type = 2 
AND create_time BETWEEN date('2011-11-08 00:00:00') AND date('2011-11-10 00:00:00')
```

Below is my table structure. I know there is date in my table, I am using SQLite browser and check the data in DB.

```
CREATE TABLE `trip_mark` (
`file_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL,
`local_path` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL ,
`file_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`import_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL ,
`create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL ,
`isSyncAvailable` int(11) DEFAULT '1' ,
`syncDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL ,
`isSynced` int(11) DEFAULT '0' ,
`longitude` float DEFAULT NULL ,
`altitude` float DEFAULT NULL ,
`place_logical_name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL ,
`file_note` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL )
```

Here is the table current data

```
"1","/sdcard/TripMark_1323375027.jpg","2","2011-11-09 01:10:37","2011-11-09 01:10:37","1","null","0","-1","-1","Unknown Location","");
"2","/sdcard/TripMark_1323375053.jpg","2","2011-02-09 01:11:01","2011-02-09 01:11:01","1","null","0","-1","-1","Unknown Location","");
"3","/sdcard/TripMark_1323375260.jpg","2","2011-11-09 01:14:29","2011-11-09 01:14:29","1","null","0","-1","-1","Unknown Location","sdfas");
```

I want to run this query

```
SELECT * FROM trip_mark WHERE file_type = 2 
AND create_time BETWEEN date('2011-11-08 00:00:00') AND date('2011-11-10 00:00:00')
```

and the expected output data is

```
"1","/sdcard/TripMark_1323375027.jpg","2","2011-11-09 01:10:37","2011-11-09 01:10:37","1","null","0","-1","-1","Unknown Location",""
"3","/sdcard/TripMark_1323375260.jpg","2","2011-11-09 01:14:29","2011-11-09 01:14:29","1","null","0","-1","-1","Unknown Location","sdfas"
```

Comment: What output did you get?  What was the expected output?

Comment: I got no exception no result. Expected output is 2 rows

Comment: **What** two rows?  Give us some sample input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: I am edit my question, Please check now

Comment: Again, what was the expected output?  What was the actual output?

Comment: And **what was the actual output**?

Comment: No output was shown. Also no syntax error in query.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite doesn't have `datetime`,`float`,`int`,`varchar` data types. See a list of available types here:
http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Thanks , You will also wonder if you run the above table creation query into SQLite browser or into android. It execute stressful. What can be the reason?

What I am asking is about the error in query

Comment: try this: `SELECT * FROM trip_mark WHERE file_type = 2 
AND create_time > date('2011-11-08 00:00:00') AND create_time < date('2011-11-10 00:00:00')`

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem. What I found that **date** function is causing problem. As the String in **' '** is already a date. I remove **date function** from the query and it worked for me. You can also try this query.

```
SELECT * FROM trip_mark WHERE file_type = 2 
AND create_time BETWEEN '2011-11-08 00:00:00' AND '2011-11-10 00:00:00'
```

Comment: what's wrong with my query? SELECT * FROM transactionList WHERE transactionDate BETWEEN  '2018-05-28  ' AND  '2018-04-28 ' LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're query didn't show any error it means it is correct. Make sure thought that there's a record in your database with `file_type = 2`.

Edit:
Given your sample data. You are storing string on your file_type. Remove the quotation marks on the file_type.

Comment: Please check the table data at the end of question, each file type is 2

Comment: You are storing string data on your file_type column that should have been an integer.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM transactionList
WHERE transactionDate BETWEEN '2018-04-29' AND '2018-05-29'
LIMIT 20;

try this query and it will work like wow :)

Please check the question

[Filter Not Working on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577341/filter-not-working-on-date/50577386#50577386)