# Filter Not Working on date

Tags: sqlite

Please help me in applying a filter I am using a query, but it's not working in my case

```
SELECT *
FROM transactionList
WHERE transactionDate >= '2018-05-29' AND transactionDate <= '2018-04-29'
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the date range backwards.  You probably intended to find all records whose transactions took place between 29-April-2018 and 29-May-2018:

```
SELECT *
FROM transactionList
WHERE transactionDate BETWEEN '2018-04-29' AND '2018-05-29'
LIMIT 20;
```

Note that in this case you may use the `BETWEEN` operator, which is inclusive on both ends, instead of the more verbose way you phrased the date range.

Comment: I tried this also but this is also not working in my case no sqlite error and no data after applying filter....SELECT * FROM transactionList WHERE transactionDate BETWEEN '2018-05-29' AND '2018-04-29' LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0

Comment: @user3475052 You _still_ have the date range backwards.  With `BETWEEN` the _earlier_ date comes first, followed by the _later_ date.  Please try running my _exact_ query, thanks.